# How to change the Admin session time in Magento?

Tags: magento2, admin, configuration

It is possible that sometimes the time that the admin session is active is too short.

**How to change the time it takes to auto-logoff the user from the back-end?**

Answer (score 30):

There's an menu item for this in:

**Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security > Session Lifetime (Seconds)**

Also check the php environment variables

- php_value session.cookie_lifetime `<seconds>`
- php_value session.gc_maxlifetime `<seconds>`

In order to ensure that you are editing the correct php.ini, create a simple "check.php" file with the following content:

```
<?php 
phpinfo();
?>
```

, place the file in your magento home directory, call it from your browser  (URL/check.php) and check these settings.

For more informations look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime).

Answer (score 18):

### Solution for Magento 2.0

For Magento 2 it can be found in Left Hand Panel on the Admin.

> Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security

`Admin Session Lifetime` (seconds) option in the main window.

Default value is 900 for Magento 2.  For 1 hour set to `3600` (60seconds * 60minutes).

You must configure this on the "Default Config" instead of selecting a website or store view for your store view option.  I tried to use it on a store view via the drop down menu in the top left and the option is not there.  It does make sense since it is an administration configuration.

**Note that this setting does not have any effect on the cookie lifetime at least since Magento 2.1**

Comment: Seems to be working for me on 2.1 right now, at least in developer mode if that matters.

Comment: Broken in 2.1.1, always session cookie

Comment: It works for my Magento v.2.3.1

Answer (score 4):

Another simple solution without modifing any settings is install any  `auto refresh addon` for your browser and set its time (60 seconds).

It will auto refresh the page for every 6o seconds which prevents session lifetime to expire and we can start working on another tab.

I used `Easy Auto Refresh` and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

System -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Session Cookie management

Cookie Lifetime: Change this value (i.e.: 86400).

Comment: Sorry, but this is the value for the session lifetime in the frontend (shop). The admin session lifetime can be set via System > Configuration > Advanced Section > Admin > Session Lifetime (seconds).
Set it to 3600 (60 seconds * 60 minutes) for a lifetime of one hour.

Comment: @AnnaVölkl I've wrote a detail post on this. http://magento2training.com/magento-admin-session-timeout-solution-that-really-works/

Answer (score 2):

Check attached image screenshot below from Magento 2 admin panel to setup session for login user.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Solution for Magento 2.1+

Since Magento 2.1 the admin session lifetime is always "session", i.e. until the browser is closed. **This has been introduced for security reasons.**

The relevant code is in `Magento\Backend\Model\Session\AdminConfig`:

```
/**
 * Set session cookie lifetime to session duration
 *
 * @return $this
 */
protected function configureCookieLifetime()
{
    return $this->setCookieLifetime(0);
}
```

If you want to change this behavior, you can add a plugin for this class with the following interceptor method:

```
public function beforeSetCookieLifetime()
{
    $lifetime = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        \Magento\Framework\Session\Config::XML_PATH_COOKIE_LIFETIME,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
    return [$lifetime, \Magento\Framework\Session\Config::COOKIE_LIFETIME_DEFAULT];
}
```

Where `$this->scopeConfig` should be an instance of `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface`, injected via constructor parameter.

This way the cookie lifetime is used from configuration, just as in the frontend.

Note that the configuration in *Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Admin Security > Session Lifetime* does not have any effect on the cookies anymore! It is used to determine Redis session lifetime, so if you increase the cookie lifetime, you should also increase this value.

Answer (score 2):

Or use the cli command tool to one one year like so:

```
bin/magento config:set admin/security/session_lifetime 31536000
```

Answer (score 1):

Sunovisio actually provide an extension that allows you to keep your administration session alive while you are working on and that independently of your session timeout.

You can check it there: http://ecommerce.sunovisio.com/index.php/admin-keep-alive-1-1-0.html

Hope this extension will help you working with your Magento Administration Panel!

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL:

table: core_config_data

path: admin/security/session_lifetime

Answer (score 0):

yes, but first you have to make sure that magento location and the server time are in the same timezone. also make sure there are no any session.* overrides in php.ini