# Magento admin user logging-out after some time

Tags: admin, session, magento-1.9.2.1

I am facing an issue in **Magento 1.9.2.1** that is my admin user is getting 
logged-out automatically after few minutes.

I have checked in back-end for the settings and all seems correct.

This majorly happens, when on front-end any guest user is adding product to the cart which actually not getting added sometimes and hence at admin end, the user logs out automatically.

Comment: System -> Configuration General > Web Session Cookie management

Cookie Lifetime: Change this value (i.e.: 86400).http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/20987/how-to-change-the-admin-session-time-in-magento

Comment: I have already set that but still admin is logging-out automatically after sometime, It is majorly happening when some guest user is trying to add to cart and actually after adding, cart shows empty..and there in admin end, it logs out

Comment: @Negin Nickparsa: I already set that in backend but then also admin is getting logged out automatically after sometime..It is majorly happening when any guest user is adding to cart and in real product is not getting added to cart for them because cart shows empty..and there at the same time in admin end, it logs out..

Comment: What is your session handler in your `local.xml`?

Comment: @BOOMER: it is memcache  
<session_save><![CDATA[memcache]]></session_save>

Comment: go to your core_config_data table in phpmyadmin and tell me the path values you have in web/cookie/cookie_path web/cookie/cookie_domain do you have them?

Comment: also does it happen in your local host or domain.com? if it is localhost try to change it to 127.0.0.1 and see if it does work?

Comment: @Negin Nickparsa: web/cookie/cookie_path and web/cookie/cookie_domain is having NULL value.. Previously also, it was null and was working

Comment: I also noticed that admin is getting logged out whenever there is any order placed in frontend..Alongwith this, several times, guest user are unable to add product to their cart but its not the case with logged-in user..Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice that in my case it was a session issue instead a code issue. I have memcache enabled and after the site upgrade, it caused some configuration issue in memcache due to which session was lost whenever a request was hitting to the server. So, what I did is I enabled file caching and disabled memcache and there is no session lost anymore and thus admin is not getting logged out.

Comment: I'm happy you found it! and thank you that you posted